# How to join two RDDs with mutually exclusive keys

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

Say I have two Spark RDDs with the following values

```
x = [(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

and

```
y = [(3, 5), (4, 7)]
```

and I want to have

```
z = [(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 7)]
```

How can I achieve this. I know you can use outerJoin followed by map to achieve this, but is there a more direct way for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rdd.union(otherRDD)` gives you the union of the two rdds as expected in the question

`x.union(y)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `+` operator. In the context of lists, this is a concatenate operation.

```
>>> x = [(1, 3), (2, 4)]
>>> y = [(3, 5), (4, 7)]
>>> z = x + y
>>> z
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 7)]
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `+` over `extend()`?

Comment: @IanAuld `extend` will modify the list in place, `+` will create and return a new list.

Comment: @MetallicPriest I don't know much (read: anything) about Spark, I was just answering with respect to Python, since you tagged Python.